# Mysql CONCAT error when loading data

Tags: mysql, sql, variables, concatenation

I am developing a sql script that loads a `.csv` file stored in an S3 bucket into an RDS DB.  The `LOAD` command works perfectly when not using `CONCAT`.  I am using `CONCAT` to include variables with the statement.  I believe the issue is with one or more of the clauses.  I significantly shorted the fields for troubleshooting purposes.  I have tried several different things, but can't seem to get the correct syntax.

```
set @s3intotemp = CONCAT('
LOAD DATA FROM S3 PREFIX "`',@workingdir, '`"
INTO TABLE `',@rndtable, '` 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ","
ESCAPED BY ""
ENCLOSED BY "\""
LINES TERMINATED BY "\n"
(@col1,
@col2) 
SET customer=@col1,
firstname=@col2;
');
PREPARE stmt from @s3intotemp;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

I am getting the following error:

> SQL Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '" (@col1, @col2 )  SET customer=@col1, firstname=@col2' at line
>   6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape the backslashes in the string, so they'll make it into the result of the concatenation.

```
set @s3intotemp = CONCAT('
LOAD DATA FROM S3 PREFIX "`',@workingdir, '`"
INTO TABLE `',@rndtable, '` 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ","
ESCAPED BY ""
ENCLOSED BY "\\\""
LINES TERMINATED BY "\\n"
(@col1,
@col2) 
SET customer=@col1,
firstname=@col2;
');
```

Comment: That is producing another error.  SQL Error: This command is not supported in the prepared statement protocol yet.  I thought maybe the issue might be the statement is trying to interpret the at sign in col1 and col2 as a variable.  I tried escaping \@col1 and \@col2, but that is not working either.

Comment: I think that means you can't use `LOAD DATA FROM S3` with a prepared statement.

Comment: I believe you are correct regarding the prepared statement.  Is the \\\ correct in the ENCLOSED BY or should it just be \\